# Android - Multiple alarms w/ pending intents, how to determine which intent is being called?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, alarmmanager

I'm working with 2 separate alarms. I have a method in my class which creates 2 different pending intents to start 2 alarms. This method calls the broadcast method when complete however depending on which intent it receives i need to perform different actions

thanks in advance,

Andy

prompt class

```
public void setSleepPrompts(Context context){
    try{
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, SleepPromptReceiver.class ); 
        PendingIntent firstSender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1, intent, 0);
        PendingIntent secondSender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 2, intent, 0);

        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, (this.getBedTimeEpoch() - this.firstPromptOffset), firstSender);
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, (this.getBedTimeEpoch() - this.secondPromptOffset), secondSender);
    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.i(TAG, e.toString());
    }
}
```

Broadcast receiver class

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    try{
        if(intent.GET_THE_INTENT_ID?)
        Toast.makeText(context, "kapow chow", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(context, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `intent.putExtra("id", "intent x")` when you create the intent, and then

```
if(intent.getStringExtra("id").equals("intent x"))
        Toast.makeText(context, "kapow chow", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: thanks for being so quick :) I was wondering if you could use the intent ID but I'm probably going to use this instead